# How to type this Gremlin response in Java?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

I want to do the following gremlin query:

```
results = traversal.path().by(valueMap()).toList();
```

I would like to take these objects and ship them back to a strongly typed API. To do that I have to do some unwinding on the gremlin side of things. But first I need a type for the object.

So... what's the return type here? Can I get the return type without casting to `Object`? Is there any way to inspect this in Java at runtime or something or is Java just unusable as I always suspected?

The IDE offers no suggestion and is giving me a scary warning:

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to
> 'java.util.List<java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>>'. ** this is what I'm trying for now**
> Reason: 'traversal.path().by(valueMap())' has raw type, so result of
> toList is erased

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result type of the path() step from:

```
gremlin> g.V().path().by(valueMap()).next().getClass()
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.MutablePath
```

You can find the corresponding interface at:
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/step/util/MutablePath.html

So, in terms of interfaces the result type is:

```
List<Path<Map<String, Object>>>
```

If you want the result type in terms of actual classes, you can do:

```
gremlin> g.V().path().by(valueMap()).toList().getClass()
==>class java.util.ArrayList
gremlin> g.V().valueMap().next().getClass()
==>class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

and you get:

```
ArrayList<MutablePath<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>>
```